# Как применить стиль к одному какому-то символу?

Tags: html, css, javascript

У меня есть следующий код:

```
<p>admin@site.ru<br>support@site.ru</p>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы собака(@) везде выделялась этим цветом #3A9ABE?

Comment: Стиль может применяться только к тэгам, а не к голому тексту, так что без дополнительной разметки Вам не обойтись, даже если Вы будете выделять определенные символы с помощью скрипта, то скрипту понадобится каждый раз обрамлять символы тэгами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p>
admin<span class="dog">@</span>site.ru<br />
support<span class="dog">@</span>site.ru
</p>
<style type="text/css"> .dog { color: #3A9ABE; } </style>
```

**UPD** код рабочий, проверил. вместо "replaceDogs('footer')" можете вызывать несколько раз с вашими ID.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- код head -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceDogs(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.split('@').join('<span style="color: #3A9ABE;">@</span>');
      }
    if (document.all) {
      document.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (document.readyState != 'complete') return false;
        replaceDogs('footer');
        }
      } else window.onload = function() {
        replaceDogs('footer');
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- код сайта -->
    <div id="footer">admin@site.ru</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я тоже так пробовал, но мне хотелось бы что бы было оставалось  
<p>admin@site.ru<br>support@site.ru</p>  
А где-то в head было что то вроде скрипта, что бы каждый раз когда я печатаю собаку она была синей.

Comment: Цвет в любом случае задается стилем. Я могу подсказать и скрипт, но по сути он все равно заменит '@' на 
<pre><span class="dog">@</span></pre> Уточните, если вы хотите, чтоб хтмл остался тот же вообще - так нельзя. Если вы просто не хотите перебивать собаки руками - можно скриптом. Но, честно, проще стилями, если не собираетесь это вбивать ежедневно в разных местах сайта.

Comment: У меня сайт сконструирован с помощью php поэтому вбивать его снова и снова не придется, подскажите скрипт.

Comment: Я ж и говорю, проще стилем вписать, если изменяться часто не будет) в любом случае нужен какой-то идентификатор блока, где собаки нужно заменять. По всему сайту - так он заменит и css @import и еще много всего. Ща...

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i = 0;
while(a[i])
{
    if(/([a-zA-Z0-9-.])@([a-zA-Z0-9-.])/.test(a[i].innerHTML))
        a[i].innerHTML = a[i].innerHTML.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9-.])@([a-zA-Z0-9-.])/g, '$1<span class="dog">@</span>$2');
    ++i;
}
```

Вот так собачка ловится только в мыльниках.

Comment: Так а стили не надо?  
Я мыло должен в span писать?

Comment: Стили - обязательно. Мыло можно писать где угодно - спаны добавятся сами.

Answer (score 1):

Тут я вижу выход только в том, чтобы написать JavaScript-код для страницы. Он должен будет находить все символы `"@"` и применять к ним стиль. А именно, заносить в тег.
Как вариант конкретной реализации, могу предложить пользоваться jQuery.

```
var originalText = $("#div_id").text();// Берем текст из элемента, в котором надо 
//выделить все собаки синим.
//
/*
Далее Вам надо написать скрипт, который находит в originalText символы 
"@" и меняет его на <span class="dog">@</span>. В JavaScript есть какая-то функция,
которая находит и заменяет один текст на другой.
*/
//Затем
$("#div_id").text(newText);
```